# How to position nested form elements in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I am creating a Rails 3 app that makes use of a nested form with two levels of nested attributes, i.e.

```
<%= form_for @workareas do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :workarea_name %>
   <%= f.fields_for :projects  do |project| %>
      <%= f.text_field :project_name %>
      <%= f.fields_for :tasks  do |task| %>
         <%= f.text_field :task_name %>   
         <%= f.check_box :complete %>
         <%= f.check_box :urgent %>
         <%= f.check_box :today %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

(I realize this pseudocode is not 100% valid)

I'm using cocoon to handle nested forms. I was using Ryan's nested_forms, but switched as Coccon seemed better able to deal with this issue.

I would like to display the tasks within a table, something like:

```
<table class="tasks">
  <tr>
    <th><%= f.label :task_name %></th>
    <th><%= f.label :complete %></th>
    <th><%= f.label :urgent %></th>
    <th><%= f.label :today %></th>
  </tr>
  <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task| %>  
    <tr>
       <td><%= f.text_field :task_name %></td>
       <td><%= f.check_box :complete %></td>
       <td><%= f.check_box :urgent %></td>
       <td><%= f.check_box :today %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= link_to_add_association "New Task", f, :tasks %>
```

I'm running into problems inserting new tasks into the correct location in the layout. This is because there will be multiple task tables, one under each project on the view.

I realize I can use a script to specify the position where fields are added:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.add_fields.").
      data("association-insertion-position", 'after').
      data("association-insertion-node", '.tasks tr:last');
});
```

But can't figure out how to pass in which project the tasks belong to. For example, if I have two projects, and try to add tasks to the 2nd project, the fields are currently being added to the 1st project. (They are correctly associated with project 2 on save however, this is purely a layout issue).

Has anyone run into this issue before? Is there a better selector to use for the "association-insertion-node". I'd welcome any pointers or suggestions.

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

I still haven't managed to find a solution to this. Essentially what I want to do is add nested child elements, contained within a `<tr>` block, to a parent form. I have not been able to make this work the way I would like/ expect.

As an interim solution, I am now rendering the child elements within a `<li>` block. The `<li>` block contains a complete `<table><tbody><tr>` block for each child. This is less than ideal in terms of formatting, but the best I'be been able to come up with.

I'm going to leave this question open, for the time being at least, in the hopes that someone can provide a better solution.

Thanks to everyone that has replied so far.

Comment: Have you tried appending the project id to the class for each table? Class="project_#{project.id}" and appending the project.id to a data attribute as well?

Comment: Thanks fatfrog, thats exactly what I need to do, but I can't work out the syntax to display the project.id. Your example returns `#{project.id}` in the html markup. I need to put some erb in there, but am being slow and can't figure out the valid syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't very clear. I can add the project.id to the table class. But I can't work out the syntax to add the project.id to the function's data attribute.

Comment: Hi @fatfrog, using this approach, how would I handle new records? E.G. Say I create a new project, then need to create 3 tasks, the project will not have an ID until saved, correct?

Comment: Instead of project_{#project.id} you can use dom_id(project) - are you familiar with the dom_id helper? It's demonstrated at the end of this Railscast (4:30) http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised?autoplay=true

Comment: Hi @fatfrog, just gave dom_id a whirl. Unfortunately it behaves in a similar manner to project.id, in that if I create multiple new projects, they will all have the same ID - `new_project`. I guess the only way to resolve this is to run a javascript function when add_new_project is clicked, that saves all projects before opening the new one? Unless I've missed something.

Comment: I didn't realize you where going to have multiple unsaved projects going - probably a good thing you couldn't make it work :)  What you might want to try is have a boolean on your project table called "temp" which is auto assigned true on creation, and create the table immediately.  The first task that is created would then change the  Temp boolean to false after save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an easy way to solve this.

In the end I had to over ride cocoon's javascript with a custom function that essentially constructs a new association object name, and appends the new association object to the existing sequence.

Not an easy solution. I will share it with Cocoon's developer and maybe the gem can be updated to offer this functionality.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I am very interested to see what you did, from the explanation it is not entirely clear to me. It could be interesting indeed to include in the gem.

Comment: hi nathanvda, I'll send you a link to the code, sorry I forgot about this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your tables are displayed, and my JS is a bit rusty, but you can pass a data attribute in the link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to_add_association "New Task", f, :tasks, 'data-project_id' => "project_#{project.id}" %>
```

then in your function:

```
var project_id = $(this).data("project_id");
$("#" + project_id + " a.add_fields.").
```

A pretty good tutorial where they do this is on CodeSchool.com with jQuery Air: Captain's Log